# How to distinguish chaos from inaccurate?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, chaos-theory

If you have a system of ODE that gives rise to a chaotic system, you can easily find that the solutions either explicit or implicit are drastically different from real-world results. Yet, this does not mean the model is inaccurate, only that you didn't pick the correct infinitesimally precise initial conditions to perfectly match physical reality.

In practice, how can you distinguish between an accurate model that is chaotic and a model that actually is inaccurate?

Comment: You mean like predicting weather, where you can have both, insufficiently accurate observations about the current state and models that by necessity can not incorporate the full physical theory (if the grid is too fine, apart from the unpractical computational complexits, the atmosphere model would also simulate low-frequency sound waves with wave lengths of hundreds of meters)?

Comment: Of course you can you have both. But is there any limit on chaos that lets you distinguish one from the other? For instance, let's say due to chaotic conditions, the current weather prediction method failed to produce reasonable results. Obviously a conventional model isn't magically a garbage model all of a sudden, so how do distinguish the chaos from a model being inadequate?